# Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Date' in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I declared a variable to display the today's date.

```
today : Date = new Date();
```

I retrieve the informations via the console...

[image]

Now, I would like to create a variable to retrieve the day from the today's date.

I created the variable -> `day`.

```
today : Date = new Date();
day: Date;
```

I have an error message ->

```
error TS2564: Property 'day' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the 
constructor.
```

I don't understand the problem?

Here is my code, thank for your help.

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  today : Date = new Date();
  day: Date;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.day = this.today.getDate();

    console.log("Today => " + this.today);
    console.log("Day => " + this.day);        
  }

}
```

Comment: `getDate()` returns the day number of the month, which is the `number` type. You can't assign to the `day` variable due to the type is unmatched.

Comment: The error message is very clear; it expects you to assign a value to `day` either when you declare it or in the constructor, but you're not doing so anywhere, hence the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two options to address this error:

```
error TS2564: Property 'day' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the 
constructor.
```

1. Initialise property in constructor

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  today : Date = new Date();
  day: Date;


  constructor() {
      day = new Date();
  }
// ...
}
```

2. Initialise property inline

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  today : Date = new Date();
  day: Date | undefined = undefined;
// ...
}
```